# Perform block for each satisfied condition, otherwise perform other block

Tags: iteration, enumeration, smalltalk, pharo

Imagine that you have to select some values and for each of them you have to evaluate a block. On the other hand if there is no value that satisfies the condition another block has to be evaluated.

**Example:**
Consider the next method signature:

```
forPositivesOf: aCollection do: aBlock otherwise: defaultBlock
```

This method should evaluate a block `aBlock` with every positive element of `aCollection`, but if there are no elements like that, evaluate `defaultBlock`. Please note that in reality the method may calculate something more complex than just positive numbers, and instead of aCollection there can be a much complex object.

Comment: When you say, *satisfies the condition*, what condition are you referring to? Do you mean that don't meet the initial select criterion? Or is there some result of the first block that you mean?

Comment: @lurker it's an internal condition defined by the method. So method checks for something, and you pass what to perform the check on, what to do for each element that satisfies the check and what to do when no elements satisfy the check.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but here are some questions: 1) What is "positice" supposed to mean? (Yes, I know it's just an example, but I'm curious...) 2) What would you be sending this message to? Why not implement it on the collection? 3) What is the actual question - are you asking what the best approach would be to coding this?

Comment: 1) I guess it meant `positivesOf`, a better selector would be `forEachPositiveIn:do:ifNone`. 2) Seems to be a proof of concept of some kind. Extending any of the the Collection classes means polluting the protocol of all its subclasses and making them follow the contract of supporting such selector, which for one particular use is not worth it. 3) He's looking for other ways to implement such feature. Maybe using less intermediate objects, doing fewer passes through the collections (as the second alternative does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Uko's solution a bit further:

```
forPositivesOf: aCollection do: aBlock otherwise: defaultBlock
    ^ (aCollection
          select: #positive
          thenCollect: aBlock
      ) ifEmpty: defaultBlock
```

Comment: This is nice. However, in my answer aBlock is wrapped in another one to perform #cull: on it and not #value:

Comment: Yes I saw your intention to allow a 0-arg block as aBlock. But in your question you wrote "... should evaluate a block aBlock with every positive element...", so I think it is fair to assume that aBlock expects a single argument, as most (all?) do: blocks do.

Comment: makes sense. I like to make it flexible, but in this case it probably does not make any sense

Answer (score 4):

A more compact version of the first alternative is the following that doesn't instantiate a new closure, and just uses the ones received as arguments.

```
forPositivesOf: aCollection do: aBlock otherwise: defaultBlock

    ^(aCollection select: [:each | each positive ]) 
         ifEmpty: defaultBlock
         ifNotEmpty: [ :collection | collection do: aBlock ]
```

Comment: I think you're meant to evaluate `defaultBlock` - you're just returning it. Also, you don't evaluate `aBlock` by calling `do: aBlock`.

Comment: No. The operation selects the elements satisfying the condition (positive numbers in this case) in `aCollection`, if no one is found (it is, there is no element satisfying the condition), then the `defaultBlock` is evaluated, if not, then `aBlock` will be evaluated with each element that satisfies the original condition.

The difference with the originally proposed code is that this one avoids the instantation of new closures.

Comment: But in this case you cannot use optional `cull:` on `aBlock`

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I see two solutions:

**1)**

```
forPositivesOf: aCollection do: aBlock otherwise: defaultBlock
  (aCollection select: #positive)
    ifEmpty: [ defaultBlock value ]
    ifNotEmpty: [ :collection |
      collection do: [ :el | aBlock cull: el ] ]
```

but in case calculation of `positive` is expensive it would be good to evaluate `aBlock` for the first encountered element, as then the one who passed `aBlock` will be able to react in any desired way.

**2)**

```
forPositivesOf: aCollection do: aBlock otherwise: defaultBlock
  | encountered |
  encountered := false.
  aCollection do: [ :el |
    el positive ifTrue: [
      encountered := true.
      aBlock cull: el ] ].

  encountered ifFalse: [
    defaultBlock value ]
```

But I don't like the extra encountered variable, it makes code less functional.

Comment: For your first example, what should `aCollection select: #positive` do? The method `select:` expects a block, not a symbol. For the second one, why are you using `cull:`? Can `aBlock` have a variable number of arguments? I'm confused.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter VW, Squeak and Pharo have redefined Symbol>>value: anObject ^anObject perform: self, so that Symbol are polymorphic to blocks.

Comment: like Amos, I don't well see the necessity of cull... Every thing named do: takes a unary block and we take it for granted here too.

Comment: @aka.nice: Thanks, wasn't aware of that... nifty :-)

Answer (score 0):

One really nice functional way that works for *SequenceableCollection*s:

```
forPositivesOf: aCollection do: aBlock otherwise: defaultBlock
  (aCollection
    select: #positive
    thenCollect: [ :el | aBlock cull: el ]) ifEmpty: [ defaultBlock value ]
```